# Fetch User input value to class

Tags: apex, controller, visualforce

I want to have an User input value from Apex page into class and put it in a string. Can someone show me the way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller code:

```
public class dummyController{
    public string userInput{get;set;}
    public dummyController(){

   }
   public void savemethod()
  {
        system.debug('--------------'+userInput);
       //your logic here
  }
}
```

---

-- VF Page --

```
<Apex:page controller="dummyController">
     <Apex:form>
          <Apex:pageblock>
               <apex:inputtext value="{!userInput}"/>
          </apex:pageBlock>
         <apex:commandbutton value="Save" action="{!savemethod}" />
     </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your controller code:

```
public class YourController{
    public string userInput{get;set;}
    public YourController(){

}
}
```

vf code --

```
<Apex:page controller="YourController">
     <Apex:form>
          <Apex:pageblock>
               <apex:inputtext value="{!userInput}"/>
          </apex:pageBlock>
     </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```